# Test connectivity to hosts in file on port 22 with curl command

Tags: shell-script, ssh, curl

Id like to plug the following "curl" command into a bash script and run it against a hostfile of ip addresses then display the output as success or failure in an output file.

```
curl -v telnet 10.10.10.10:22
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

I don't yet have the reputation necessary to comment on the post that claims curl isn't for ssh or telnet. That is not accurate. Curl handles a multitude of protocols, including telnet, ssh, scp, sftp, ftps, and more.

This is the correct syntax for curl:

```
curl -v telnet://127.0.0.1:22
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the bash builtin to check for open ports may work as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

host_file=/path/to/file.txt
out_file=/path/to/out.txt

while read -r ip; do
    if timeout 5 bash -c "cat < /dev/null >/dev/tcp/${ip}/22"; then
        echo -e "${ip}\tSuccess"
    else
        echo -e "${ip}\tFailure" 
    fi >> "$out_file"
done < "$host_file"
```

Comment: I didn't know this one. Is it documented anywhere? Does it also work with IPv6?

Comment: @Tomasz: It's documented in the bash reference manual [3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections).  I'm unsure if it works with ipv6.

Answer (score 3):

`curl` is generally used for HTTP / HTTPS / FTP; not so much for SSH or Telnet.

I'd just use netcat:

```
testport=22 # 22 for ssh; 23 for telnet; 80 for HTTP; etc.
while read ip; do
    if nc -w2 -z $ip $testport; then
        echo $ip up
    else
        echo $ip down
    fi >> testresults.txt
done < hostlist.txt
```

Comment: cURL docs list TELNET - https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html